# Browser tool to save HTML branch?

Tags: html

I'm frequently finding myself wanting to pick an element in a webpage document inspector, and save it to file.

For example, I'd like to save a form on a page. I can open up the document in say, Chrome's object inspector, identify the: ... content, but I have no way of saving this branch of the document.

Is there a browser/browser-plugin that would like me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome dev tools you can go to the Elements view, right click the opening tag of the element required and select Copy as HTML. This places the HTML for the element and all its children onto the clipboard for you. You can then save this into a new text file or paste into an HTML editor